# kafka streaming behaviour for more than one partition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am consuming from Kafka topic. This topic has 3 partitions.
I am using foreachRDD to process each batch RDD (using processData method to process each RDD, and ultimately create a DataSet from that).

Now, you can see that i have count variable , and i am incrementing this count variable in "processData" method to check how many actual records i have processed. (i understand , each RDD is collection of kafka topic records , and the number depends on batch interval size)

Now , the output is something like this :

1 1 1 2 3 2 4 3 5 ....

This makes me think that its because i might have 3 consumers( as i have 3 partitions), and each of these will call "foreachRDD" method separately, so the same count is being printed more than once, as each consumer might have cached its copy of count.

But the final output DataSet that i get has all the records.

So , does Spark internally union all the data? How does it makes out what to union?
I am trying to understand the behaviour , so that i can form my logic

int count = 0;

```
messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<K, String>>>() {
            public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> rdd) {
                System.out.println("NUmber of elements in RDD : "+ rdd.count());

                List<Row> rows = rdd.map(record -> processData(record))
                        .reduce((rows1, rows2) -> {
                            rows1.addAll(rows2);
                            return rows1;
                        });

                StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
                Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
                ds.createOrReplaceTempView("trades");                
                ds.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions are not completely accurate.
`foreachRDD` is one of the so-called `output operations` in Spark Streaming. The function of `output operations` is to schedule the provided closure at the interval dictated by the `batch interval`. The code in that closure executes once each `batch interval` on the spark driver. Not distributed in the cluster.

In particular, `foreachRDD` is a general purpose `output operation` that provides access to the underlying RDD within the DStream. Operations applied on that RDD will execute on the Spark cluster.

So, coming back to the code of the original question, code in the `foreachRDD` closure such as `System.out.println("NUmber of elements in RDD : "+ rdd.count());` executes on the driver. That's also the reason why we can see the output in the console. Note that the `rdd.count()` in this `print` will trigger a `count` of the RDD on the cluster, so `count` is a distributed operation that returns a value to the driver, then -on the driver- the `print` operation takes place.

Now comes a transformation of the RDD:

```
rdd.map(record -> processData(record))
```

As we mentioned, operations applied to the `RDD` will execute on the cluster. And that execution will take place following the Spark execution model; that is, transformations are assembled into stages and applied to each partition of the underlying dataset. Given that we are dealing with 3 kafka topics, we will have 3 corresponding partitions in Spark. Hence, `processData` will be applied once to each partition.

> So, does Spark internally union all the data? How does it make out what to union?

The same way we have output operations for Spark Streaming, we have actions for Spark. Actions will potentially apply an operation to the data and bring the results to the driver. The most simple operation is `collect` which brings the complete dataset to the driver, with the risk that it might not fit in memory. Other common action, `count` summarizes the number of records in the dataset and returns a single number to the driver.

In the code above, we are using `reduce`, which is also an action that applies the provided function and brings the resulting data to the driver. It's the use of that action that is "internally union all the data" as expressed in the question. In the reduce expression, we are actually collecting all the data that was distributed into a single local collection. It would be equivalent to do:  `rdd.map(record -> processData(record)).collect()`

If the intention is to create a Dataset, we should avoid "moving" all the data to the driver first.

A better approach would be:

```
val rows = rdd.map(record -> processData(record))
val df = ss.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
...
```

In this case, the data of all partitions will remain local to the executor where they are located.

Note that moving data to the driver should be avoided. It is slow and in cases of large datasets will probably crash the job as the driver cannot typically hold all data available in a cluster.

Comment: Thanks ,very well explained. i still have below doubts:
-> Even if we have 3 partitions in a kafka topic, will we still get one RDD in a batch interval and it have data from all the 3 partitions. Then why did you say "Hence, processData will be applied once to each partition." ? I mean, only thing that spark know  is that it has one RDD, it doesn't have any info about the kafka partitions, right?

Comment: -> You said that "we should avoid moving all data to the driver" : So lets say i use "collect" and so the data will remain on the cluster. Now if i do some SQL operations on this dataset. Will i get a combined results from all partitions?

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana  re: Partitions.  Partitioning is key to Spark internal working. Whether it's batch or streaming. In the case of kafka direct consumer, Spark will create one RDD partition for each partition of a kafka topic being consumed.

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana  re: getting data. "collect" will get all data to the driver. DO NOT USE unless strictly required.  re: SQL: Yes - if you apply SQL operations, you get the combined results of all partitions. Spark will transparently handle that for you.

Comment: Finally, the approach that you suggested :
val rows = rdd.map(record -> processData(record))
val df = ss.createDataFrame(rows, schema);

Actually, my map function returns JavaRDD<List<Row>>.
This return type cannot be directly converted into a DataFrame. So, i may need to use collect(),  Any suggestion?

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana if your function returns a collection of `Row` you can flatten it using `flatMap` instead of `map`: `val rows = rdd.flatMap(record -> processData(record))`