# spark transform method behaviour in multiple partition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Kafka Streaming to read data from Kafka topic, and i want to join every RDD that i get in the stream to an existing RDD. So i think using "transform" is the best option (Unless any one disagrees, and suggest a better approach)

And, I read following example of "transform" method on DStreams in Spark:

```
val spamInfoRDD = ssc.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(...) // RDD containing spam information

val cleanedDStream = wordCounts.transform { rdd =>
  rdd.join(spamInfoRDD).filter(...) // join data stream with spam information to do data cleaning
  ...
}
```

But lets say, i have 3 partitions in the Kafka topic, and that i invoke 3 consumers to read from those. Now, this transform method will be called in three separate threads in parallel.

I am not sure if joining the RDDs in this case will be Thread-safe and this will not result in data-loss. (considering that RDDs are immutable)

Also, if you say that its thread-safe then wouldn't the performance be low since we are creating so many RDDs and then joining them?

can anybody suggest?

Comment: Are you running on a cluster? In general, the same principles I explained in your other question apply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44445834/764040  It will be useful for you to take a step back and review the Spark execution model to better understand what's going on. Answering to this question will lead to repeating what's covered already in many presentations and text books. (probably as I did on the other question. mea culpa). You could start here if you like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgvYg-0OXkU&t=7s